# Prestashop clients can't login

Tags: php, cookies, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop store http://miplata.es/ and currently many clients complain that they can't login the store. I am currently unable to pinpoint the issue but I think it might be something with the cookies or the login module of the store.

However some clients are able to enter and some are not and this is across multiple browsers, not only one. I am currently with the latest version of Prestashop.

Comment: A new member has suggested that the OP look at the [support forums](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/). I'll copy that advice here, since their answer is likely to be deleted (flagged as "not an answer").